# Creating histogram bins from Django queries

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to create bins with the count of prices to be used for a histogram. 
I want the bins to be 0-1000, 1000-2000, 2000-3000 and so forth. If I just do group by I get way to many different bins.

The code I've written seems to end in a infinite loop (or at least the script is still running after an hour). I'm not sure how to do it correctly. Here is the code I wrote:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def price_histogram(area_id, agency_id):
    # Get prices and total count for competitors
    query = HousePrice.objects.filter(area_id=area_id, cur_price__range=(1000,30000)).exclude(agency_id=agency_id)
    count = query.values('cur_price').annotate(count=Count('cur_price')).order_by('cur_price')
    total = query.count()

    # Get prices and total count for selected agency
    query_agency = HousePrice.objects.filter(area_id=area_id, agency_id=agency_id, cur_price__range=(1000,30000))
    count_agency = query_agency.values('cur_price').annotate(count=Count('cur_price')).order_by('cur_price')
    total_agency = query_agency.count()

    # Make list for x and y values
    x_comp = []
    y_comp = []
    x_agency = []
    y_agency = []

    bin_start = 0
    bin_end = 1000
    _count_comp = 0
    _count_agency = 0

    for row_comp, row_agency in zip_longest(count, count_agency, fillvalue={}):
        while bin_start < int(row_comp['cur_price']) < bin_end:
            _count_comp += row_comp['count']
            _count_agency += row_agency.get('count', 0)
        bin_start += 1000
        bin_end += 1000

        x_comp.append(str(bin_start) + "-" + str(bin_end) + " USD")
        x_agency.append(str(bin_start) + "-" + str(bin_end) + " USD")
        y_comp.append(_count_comp/total)
        y_agency.append(_count_agency/total_agency)

    return {'x_comp': x_comp, 'y_comp': y_comp, 'x_agency': x_agency, 'y_agency': y_agency}
```

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.10.

Comment: Have you tried using `pandas.DataFrame` for this?

Comment: no, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In SQL you'd do this with a single COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY ... query. Does the Django ORM allow you to do this? It's pretty comprehensive if rather cumbersome. Pandas is great, but ideally you don't want to have to read all those rows into memory.

Comment: @holdenweb the problem here is getting the 1000 dollar bins. By just using group by I'll get way too many bins.

Comment: Not if you group on the integer result of dividing the current price by a thousand. There's usually  more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late, but maybe the [django-pivot](https://github.com/martsberger/django-pivot) library does what you want.

```
from django_pivot.histogram import histogram

query = HousePrice.objects.filter(area_id=area_id, cur_price__range=(1000,30000)).exclude(agency_id=agency_id
hist = histogram(query, cur_price, bins=[1000:30000:1000])
```